# Is it necessary to use a non-root user?

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7

I have installed nginx on my centos 7 server, now i'm going to create a server block but i wonder if it's necessary to use a non-root user?

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7) on DigitalOcean and it states that i need a non-root user:

> You will need access to a CentOS 7 server with a non-root user that has sudo privileges.

This is my private server and i will always be the only admin of it, why can't i use root user to do it?

Comment: Necessary? No. **Wise? Yes.** See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-as-root, etc.

Comment: So, I've created a few directories which i'm going to use in my non-root user and set pm2 to start on startup (`sudo pm2 startup systemd`), do I have to change anything to make pm2 run safe & gain access to files i've created on root? It's my first time working with a server. @ceejayoz

Comment: What is pm2 meant for here? It's pretty much obsolete. And it's not even in that tutorial.

Comment: It's in [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7), i don't know if it would affect security or not if its run by root. PM2 is what i run on root, i did nothing else except creating folders and i wonder if it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once someone else gets the root access, game is over. Having a separate user for SSH login and [**disabling root login**](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-9c01429983dccbf74ade8674815980dc6434d3ba) adds an extra layer of security where an intruder needs to first be able to access the system as a normal user and then elevate privileges.

If you are the only admin, using `root` account instead of `sudo` might actually be more secure with password authentication, as there are two different passwords to know. With the login user in *sudoers* group it's better to use [SSH keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/) instead of password login, and password only for the `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think they meant **minimum** requisites. The reason you need superuser access is that you are installing a software via the `yum` package manager, and also the daemon will need root permissions to start.

So answering your question, it is ok to use a *non-root user with sudo privileges* or a *root user*